# Installed LXQT but my display manager is shown gdm3 and Desktop Environment as GNOME

Tags: desktop-environments, display-manager, lxqt

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry pi 4. Updated and upgraded. Then ran the command "$ sudo apt-get install lxqt".
After reboot I was on login screen, I could login. And when I checked desktop environment was GNOME by command 
**$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
$ ubuntu:GNOME**
was the response.
Then I ran the command
**$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
$ /usr/sbin/gdm3**
was the response.
I couldn't understand. I didn't install any DisplayManager nor WindowsManager.
Should I install any now or I am fine.

Comment: Ubuntu includes Gnome3 and gdm3. Not sure what you expect to happen. Why install Ubuntu and not Lubuntu if you wanted lxqt?

Comment: @ mikewhatever For Raspberry pi ubuntu core is installed not  full desktop. we have to install desktop after login to cli. I was trying to manually install a desktop. So I started with lxqt.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I notice that `apt install lxqt` doesn't pull in `sddm`. Maybe install `sddm`, if it isn't installed?

Comment: It is unclear where Ubuntu core comes from. It is not mentioned in the question. It is also unclear how Gnome3 got into Ubuntu Core.

Comment: @mikewhatever Downloaded from ubuntu website https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi, it doesn't have desktop preinstalled. we have to install after the first log in by using command $ apt-get install xubuntu-desktop or kubuntu or lubuntu.

Comment: @DKBose That's why this question. Because I just installed LXQT no other packages. Now it is working without any tweak settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in this problem for a quite few days. Here's how I solved this.

1. After install lubuntu-desktop (or LXQT in your case), you may probably choose lightdm as desktop manager by typing `sudo apt install lightdm` in the command-line.
2. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. This command automatically sets the default DM to lightdm.
3. `sudo reboot` and you'll see the login screen on your connected monitor. Select the upper right button and switch the default desktop to lubuntu. (If you're using remote access or running RPI4 in headless mode, the following steps can guide you through this)

For those who are also confused by the remote desktop connection when using lubuntu in Raspberry Pi 4B, the following steps may help:

1. Run `sudo apt install x11vnc`
2. Run `sudo ps wwaux | grep auth` and the outputs are like:

   root      1428  5.0  2.2 231000 42288 tty7     Ssl+ 12:47   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch

   root      1429  0.3  0.5  27496  9964 ?        Ss   12:47   0:00 /usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 -auth guess

   ubuntu    1975  0.0  0.0   5952   552 pts/0    S+   12:48   0:00 grep --color=auto auth
3. The first line (starts with root) tells Xorg-core is now using display :0 and the -auth parameter is `/var/run/lightdm/root/:0`
4. Start X11VNC by running `sudo x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0`
5. If your device is running X11VNC for the first time, the program may ask you to provide some security profiles
6. Open a VNC client on your PC and connect to RPI4 by entering the address `<IP>::5901`

The previous steps may not be successfully conducted if your RPI4 does not have a physical monitor. In this case, you may first refer to [this link](https://techoverflow.net/2019/02/23/how-to-run-x-server-using-xserver-xorg-video-dummy-driver-on-ubuntu/) to create a virtual display for Xorg.